# Set volume from terminal

Tags: command-line, audio, linux-mint

Is it possible to set the audio volume using the terminal instead of clicking the speaker icon in the top bar?

The reason I want to do this is that my keyboard does not have volume increase/decrease buttons and I find it annoying to reach for the mouse.

Comment: Read Master Volume level in number percent 0%-100%: `amixer sget Master | grep 'Right:' | awk -F'[][]' '{ print $2 }'`  Increase Master volume level by 10%: `amixer -q sset Master 10%+`

Answer (score 123, accepted):

For interactive usage you can use `alsamixer`. For scripting (e.g. binding to key combinations) take a look at `amixer`.

`alsamixer` is included by default in most systems.

---

To set the master volume use:

```
# Gets a list of simple mixer controls
$ amixer scontrols
```

Then set it to the desired volume, as an example

```
$ amixer sset 'Master' 50%
```

Comment: What is the different between "sset" and just "set". (I tried both, and both work)

Comment: @Venryx `man amixer` suggests that the they are equivalent and that the "s" in "sset" stands for "simple". There's also a "cset" that sets card control contents.

Comment: Added the following to my `.bashrc` to make this command easier: `volume() { amixer sset 'Master' $1%; }`

Answer (score 58):

Found in Openbox's configuration file `rc.xml`:

```
# increase by 3%
amixer -q sset Master 3%+

# decrease by 3%
amixer -q sset Master 3%-

# mute/unmute
amixer -q sset Master toggle
```

`amixer` manual page can give more details.

Answer (score 35):

If your system is using `pulseaudio` you could use `pactl`:

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 +15%
```

or

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 -5dB
```

though you could also specify an integer or a linear factor:

```
set-sink-volume SINK VOLUME [VOLUME ...]
          Set the volume of the specified sink (identified by its symbolic name or numerical index). VOLUME can be speci‐
          fied as an integer (e.g. 2000, 16384), a linear factor (e.g. 0.4, 1.100), a percentage (e.g. 10%, 100%) or a
          decibel value (e.g. 0dB, 20dB). If the volume specification start with a + or - the volume  adjustment  will  be
          relative to the current sink volume. A single volume value affects all channels; if multiple volume values are
          given their number has to match the sink's number of channels.
```

Comment: Note from [arch linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting): `pactl` commands that take negative percentage arguments will fail with an 'invalid option' error. Use the standard shell `--` pseudo argument to disable argument parsing before the negative argument. e.g. `pactl set-sink-volume 1 -- -5%`

Comment: @JamieCockburn - I'm not sure when was that written but _I use archlinux_ and there is absolutely no need for the additional `--` with negative values (percentage, db, integers... they all work fine). In fact, **it's quite the opposite**: if I use `--` as per the wiki e.g. `pactl set-sink-volume 1 -- -3%`  I get `Invalid volume specification`.

Comment: Must be dependent on shell then?  I'm on ubuntu 14.04, with Xfce, and running the command from bash (4.3.11).  If I omit the `--`, I get an invalid option.

Comment: @JamieCockburn - I don 't think the shell is relevant (for the record, it works fine for me with both `bash` and `zsh`). Probably earlier versions of `pactl` had this problem and upstream most likely fixed it (I'm using v. 6.0).

Comment: Right, well the standard `pactl` bundled with this distro seems to be 4.0.  Hopefully my comment this will help others facing this issue!

Comment: @JamieCockburn i'm running ubuntu 16.04 xfce bash, and it works perfectly witout "--", just a note.

Comment: In my case I wanted to control a different sink so I used `pactl set-sink-volume 1 -5dB`.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is an old one. Since Alsa and pulseaudio are so connected, this [answer from askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/444183) helped me manage the volume from both my main sound and the HDMI:

increase volume

```
amixer -q -D pulse sset Master 10%+
```

decrease volume

```
amixer -q -D pulse sset Master 10%-
```

toggle mute

```
amixer -q -D pulse sset Master toggle
```

Other amixer sset commands work too.

Answer (score 10):

These are "more natural for human ear".

To get the master in the alsamixer units, use:

```
amixer -M get Master
```

To raise the volume by 5% in the alsamixer units, for example:

```
amixer -M set Master 5%+
```

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=135348

Answer (score 7):

In OS X use the following:

```
# highest
osascript -e "set Volume 7"
# lowest
osascript -e "set Volume 1"
# middle
osascript -e "set Volume 3.5"
```

You can even set the volume to other fractional levels:

```
# 25%
osascript -e "set Volume 1.75"
```

Comment: Worth noting that you can also [use the Mac volume buttons to change volume by fractional increments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/568/151730).

Comment: @Wildcard the Mac volume buttons are only in increments of 0.25

Answer (score 6):

you can also try `pamixer`, a recent project that does exactly what you want. It is in the ArchLinux AUR repository with the same name.

Comment: it's even in community repository now

Answer (score 0):

So, answer the question first: To increase the Master volume level by 10%, consider this snippet:

```
amixer -q sset Master 10%+
```

You can also set it to a specific value:

```
amixer -q sset Master 78%
```

---

This can also be found in other answers, but I try to extend to [the comment by Eric Leschinski](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/25792/eric-leschinski), which basically is a ***TL:DR;***-ish answer.

To read the Master Volume level (human readable), you can use:

```
amixer sget Master
```

To get the number in percent (from 0% to 100%), you can pipe it into `grep` and `awk`:

```
amixer sget Master | grep 'Right:' | awk -F'[][]' '{ print $2 }'
```

On my notebook, I only have a mono-speaker, so the right code for me was:

```
amixer sget Master | grep 'Mono:' | awk -F'[][]' '{ print $2 }'
```